# Yii2 print out gridview with colors

Tags: html, css, gridview, printing, yii2

I would like to print my gridview but I can't make it look like on the screen, so there are no colors. I have tried with styling `background-color` and class and nothing seems to work. It's a monochrome laser printer and I have made sure that it's printing with colors (will be greyscale) and background colors also selected in chrome print view. I can't find any relevant info on the web either. Can you please point me to the right direction? Thank you!

I have found `@media print` in bootstrap.css:

```
@media print {
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        color: #000 !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
        background: transparent !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }
    a,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    /*a[href]:after {
      content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }*/
    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }
    a[href^="#"]:after,
    a[href^="javascript:"]:after {
        content: "";
    }
    pre,
    blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999;

        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }
    tr,
    img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }
    p,
    h2,
    h3 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }
    h2,
    h3 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
    .navbar {
        display: none;
    }
    .btn > .caret,
    .dropup > .btn > .caret {
        border-top-color: #000 !important;
    }
    .label {
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .table {
        border-collapse: collapse !important;
    }
    .table td,
    .table th {
        background-color: #fff !important;
    }
    .table-bordered th,
    .table-bordered td {
        border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
    }
}
```

I have tried to comment `.table th {` out, deleted cache but it's still without background color. Can you please tell me what a quick and dirty way would be to add the default row and cell background colors (classes) to the print? It's also okay if I just have to adjust something temporary and after printing change it back.

Comment: for print normally you should add  a proper css . for print media  ..

Comment: is there absolutely no css for printing something out by default in yii2... ?

Comment: is not Yii2 issue   .. is html  and css  compentence ..  for this there is a default for print in css ..  but not useful.. because don't use screen media css